# How can I restrict the user form using few numeric keys in a text box?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a textbox using AngularJS, in which the user is permissible to enter only the keys (1,2,3,4 & 5). *None other than these keys.

Comment: share what you have tried so far in code and ask only where you get stuck. This is not a free coding service

Comment: @Claies wouldn't `ng-pattern` merely make input invalid while OP wants user permissible to enter only specific keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  `ng-keypress="validate($event)"` for the keys and the function use in controller as below so that user permissible to enter only specific keys

In Controller Page,

```
 $scope.validate = function ($event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[1-5]");

    var key = String.fromCharCode(!$event.charCode ? $event.which : $event.charCode);

    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In Html Page,

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-keypress="validate($event)" />
```

Hope this will help you.